# Can I use java to get the remote ip address of the Sauce Labs machine running my test?

Tags: selenium, saucelabs

I want to use the Robotil class to remotely press keys on a sauce labs machine but I need the IP and port for that machine and it can change each run. Is there a way to get this in runtime using java/selenium?

Comment: Please list what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. As per [Robotil](http://codoid.com/robotil/)

> 1) Download Robotil.jar
>   2) Start Robotil server on a remote machine.

So you have to place the Robotil.jar in the remote machine and have to execute the jar file.

And SauceLabs only provides grid URL and can be used only to create RemoteDriver Instances , it wont allow you to execute shell/windows scrips or do file transfer and all.